# switch the order in a text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, notepad

I got a text file in this format:

```
ip1:user1:pass1
ip2:user2:pass2
ip3:user3:pass3
```

How can I change the order in lines to get this result?

```
user1:pass:1@ip1
user2:pass2@ip2
user3:pass3@ip3
```

Comment: should `pass:1` in output be `pass1` instead? see also  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F : '{print $2 FS $3 "@" $1}' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $2 FS $3 "@" $1}' file
```

or

```
awk -F : '{print $2 ":" $3 "@" $1}' file
```

Output:

```
user1:pass1@ip1
user2:pass2@ip2
user3:pass3@ip3
```